# in_array function doesn't work well when returning an array from a function

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function which opens a remote file to get its content with the cURL library. Then the function returns an array containing the content of the file.

Then, when it checks whether that specific value exists in the array by using the `in_array` function, it **always shows that the value doesn't exist, even though it does.**

Here's the code and also the content of remote file.

```
function getCountry($file) {
    $fop = curl_init($file);
    curl_setopt($fop, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($fop, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($fop);
    curl_close($fop);
    $fcontent = explode("\n", $result);
    return $fcontent;
}

$file = "http://localhost/countries.txt";
$countries = getCountry($file);

if (in_array('italy', $countries)) {
    echo "Exists";
} else {
    echo "Not exists";
}
```

In the content of the remote file `countries.txt`, every sentence or word in a line is like this:

```
spain
italy
norway
canada
france
```

As I mentioned previously, **it always shows that the value doesn't exist, even though it does.**

Comment: Try replacing `\n` with `\r\n`.

Comment: Nice solution and easy too (+1).

Comment: Thanks! I think that it would be better to use regex though. Check out my answer.

Comment: Replacing it with `\r\n` only moves the problem, what if a future user of your program uses another editor that only inserts LFs instead of CRLFs? Never get stuck on programming for a specific case, fix generically, for example with `$fcontent = array_map('trim', explode("\n", $result));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not sure whether there will be CRLF in the file, instead of `explode()` you can use `preg_split()` like this:

```
return preg_split('/\r?\n/', $result);
```

Alternatively, apply `trim()` to each result:

```
return array_map('trim', explode("\n", $result));
```

The latter will also remove leading and trailing spaces and tabs which may not always be suitable.

Comment: Lol, you added the `array_map` addition simultaneously with me hehe.

Answer (score 2):

I'm mighty sure you've got sparse characters such as carriage returns in your source file. Try this after the `getCountry` call:

```
foreach($countries as &$country) {
  echo "'$country' (".strlen($country).")<br>";
  $country = trim($country);
}
```

Wouldn't surprise me if it gave a `strlen` of 6 for 'italy', and fix the problem along the way.

The proper fix would be to clean up the content right after parsing:

```
$fcontent = array_map('trim', explode("\n", $result));
```

Comment: +1, this is exactly what I thought when he said he is able to retrieve the last line!

Comment: very nice, would a better step be removing all characters that aren't A to Z?

Comment: @DavidChen depends entirely on the input file, in this case I'm just suggesting to clean up the cr/lf mess.

Comment: mmhm, I was thinking that when I suggested `\r\n`, considering that the only characters possible for a country name is A-Z (English), I think it might be better to use some regular expression.

Comment: That attitude might get you into a fight with people from `South Africa`, `The Bahamas`, `Босна и Херцеговина` or `Côte d'Ivoire`.

Comment: Hahaha, but I'm assuming this is a country name file that only includes alphanumeric characters, " " should be accepted too.

Comment: Assumptions are the mother... `Côte d'Ivoire` is actually the official international name of that country   ;)

Comment: @Niels: Thanks `Niels` for your answer.